# Can not select Airplay Device in OSX

Tags: airplay

When I click on my Airplay speaker in Sound settings, it jumps back. 
I have to restart my Mac in order to fix this problem. 
[image]
How can I fix this issue without restarting my Mac?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is command line solution that I've found in [Mac Rumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=16645997&postcount=19)

```
sudo kill `ps -ax | grep 'coreaudiod' | grep 'sbin' |awk '{print $1}'`
```

Which can assigned to an alias:

```
alias fixairplay="sudo kill `ps -ax | grep 'coreaudiod' | grep 'sbin' |awk '{print $1}'`"
```

Then this command fixes the issue:

```
fixairplay
```

Comment: Works like a charm. You sir, made my day!

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to restart the coreaudio deamon (`coreaudiod`). Open up the terminal and run `sudo killall coreaudiod`. As simple as that.

Then if you're having a difficult time memorizing the above, you can add the following line to `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias fixairplay='sudo killall coreaudiod'
```

From now on you can just use the alias `fixairplay`.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from Mohsen, but simplified by using **pgrep**.

`` sudo kill `pgrep coreaudio` ``

**pgrep**'s reason for existence is to avoid parsing **ps** output and is much safer to use when being sent to **kill**, IMHO cause you are less likely to grab the wrong process info.

Anyway, the accepted answer worked great (Mavericks).

[pgrep @ wikipedia (man is waaay too obscure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same behavior with HDMI, as well. I.e. For some reason which I have yet to identify, my mac mini (running Mavericks) will switch to using the internal speakers, and any attempt to switch back to HDMI doesn't just bounces back to internal speakers.

Killing coreaudio (which will then restart itself) fixes the HDMI issue as well.  @0sh and @jl-peyret have the simplest commands, which can be entered in the terminal:

```
sudo kill `pgrep coreaudio`
```

or

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

For people who like to shy away from the terminal, you can also quit the **coreaudiod** process from the **Activity Monitor**.

There are some other recommendations, if this doesn't fix things, in [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/sound-advice-fixing-common-mac-audio-problems-os-x/), though some of them are a bit extreme.