# Can I use Airplay without Apple TV or Airport

Tags: appletv, airplay

I have my PC, IPad and a AirPlay compatible speaker

My question is:

Can I use AirPlay to hear my IPad music in my speaker only with ITunes software only, or I need necessarily to buy AppleTV or an AirPort in order to use AirPlay?

In order to use AirPlay is necessarily to have AppleTV o an AirPort??

Comment: Not direct answer to your question but  http://www.airserver.com/ makes it possible to beam your Ipad back to your mack or PC  got it as part of a bundle a while back seemed to work but have not used extensively try the free trial

Comment: I run iPad and MBP output to a Denon amp, over an ASUS router.  AirPlay compatibility seems sufficient.  Note however that Macs are occasionallt glitchy wrt selecting AirPlay outputs - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85623/can-not-select-airplay-device-in-osx/229795#229795

Answer (score 1):

Rogue Amoeba has a few applications that work together for this sort of thing. Check out Airfoil: http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/

Answer (score 1):

If the speaker supports AirPlay then it should show up as an available destination device in control center regardless of what brand of router you are running.